# Erro 500 quando usando PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Estou tentando utilizar o PHPMailer para enviar emails porém o mesmo não funciona. Me dá erro 500! Uso hostinger.com para hospedar meu site. Aqui está o código:

```
$email = new PHPMailer(true);

            //Using SMTP

            $email->IsSMTP();
            //$email->Host = "in-v3.mailjet.com";
            $email->Host = "aspmx.l.google.com";
            $email->SMTPDebug = 1;
            $email->SMTPAuth = true;
            $email->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            $email->Username = $mail;
            $email->Password = $pin;
            $email->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            $email->Port = 25;

            //Not using SMTP anymore
            try{
            $email->SetFrom (" victaliumbot@victalium.16mb.com", "Victalium");
            $email->Subject = "Account Activation";
            $email->AddAddress($mail, $user);
            $email->IsHTML(false);

            $email->MsgHTML($mail_msg);
            $email->Send();

            echo "Account created, details:<br>----------------------------------------------------<br>Username: $nick,
                         <br>Email: $mail, <br>Password: $pin.<br>----------------------------------------------------<br> Please check the verification e-mail sent to activate it :)";

            } catch (phpmailerException $e){

                echo "Error during registering, sorry :(";

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifique essas linhas:

```
$email->Host
```

Tem 2 linhas como essa. Deve conter apenas um especificando o host SMTP.

```
$email->Host = "smtp.google.com" -> caso use gmail
```

e também essa:

```
$email->Port="25"
```

As portas são: 587 se usar tls ou 465 se usar ssl na diretiva SMTPSecure.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda ;)